# Confused on producer-consumer solution (synchronization clarification)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, producer-consumer

I've been learning about concurrency in Java, and I came across the producer-consumer problem. It's apparently standard, and I've seen a near identical answer in many places.

```
public synchronized void put(int num){
    while (!empty) {
        try{
            wait(); }
        catch {}
    }

    buffer=num;
    empty=false;
    notify();
}

public synchronized int take(){
    while (empty) {
        try{
            wait(); }
        catch {}
    }

    empty=true;
    notify();
    return buffer;
}
```

My understanding of synchronized is that it uses an object-wide lock, meaning that threads couldn't be in both put and take. But, both methods wait for the other method. This is where I'm confused: this seems to create deadlock. If thread A goes into put `while empty=false`, it'll wait. Thread B, however, cannot enter take, because it's synchronized. Therefore empty will be false forever, giving deadlock.

Given how many times I've basically seen this answer, however, it seems like it must be right. What am I understanding wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `wait` will release the lock acquired when entering the method. So if A entered `put` and called `wait`, the lock is released and B can then proceed inside `take`.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

```
The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership 
of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this 
object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the 
notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the 
monitor and resumes execution.
```

Comment: Ok, that definitely helps clarify things. But, if B is inside take and calls notify(), that awakens A, but A doesn't have the lock for the method it's currently inside (because B has one more line until leaving take). So does A go back to sleep or does it wait without an actual wait()?

Comment: @Akroy, after the text that I quoted there is another sentence: "The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the 
monitor and resumes execution." I've added it to the post. Now you have the entire picture I hope.

Comment: I think so, this is becoming much more clear! Last clarification: so, if in the original situation, A was waiting, then another producer C also came in and waited within put, how would this work? Would B calling notify wake up both A and C? Or would it be a race condition of which one responded first? Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no situation where both the producer and the consumer would wait because your queue has a capacity of only 1 item (i.e. it is either empty or full which cannot occur at the same time).

Comment: But if I had two producers waiting, would it simply be nondeterministic which one awoke? Or would that create some issue?

Comment: @Akroy: when two threads are waiting, calling notify() will wake one of them nondeterministically, while notifyAll() will wake all of them.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, notifyAll would simply not be used in a monitor situation like this. I think this all makes sense then, I really appreciate your help!